# AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'log' Python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, solver

I am making a syntax error, some how my syntax is leading python to think I am writing +.log some where?
Please take a look at the code and let me know.
Can any one suggest, a function that can be used instead to solve this Algorithm

```
import numpy as np

import sympy as sp

answer = 0

x = sp.Symbol('x')

y = sp.Symbol('y')

W = sp.Symbol('W')

R = sp.Symbol('R')

a = sp.Symbol('a')

n = sp.Symbol('n')

m = sp.Symbol('m')

O = sp.Symbol('O')

'''
answer = sp.solve(((((-1* (np.log(1+(x/R))))/(np.log(1+((10**6)/R))))+1)*(Os/((np.log(np.exp(1)+(x/a)**n))**m)))-W,x)
'''

answer = sp.solve(((((-1* (sp.log(1+(x/R))))/(sp.log(1+((10**6)/R))))+1)*(O/((sp.log(np.exp(1)+(x/a)**n))**m)))-W,x)

print(answer)
```

Results:
OLD

```
line 15, in <module>
    answer = sp.solve(((((-1* (np.log(1+(x/R))))/(np.log(1+((10**6)/R))))+1)*(Os/((np.log(np.exp(1)+(x/a)**n))**m)))-W,x)
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'log'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Results:
New

```
 Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1414, in _solve
    "\nNo algorithms are implemented to solve equation %s" % f)
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [log((x/a)**n + 54365636569181/20000000000000)**m, log(1 + x/R)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation O*(1 - log(1 + x/R)/log(1 + 1000000/R))*log((x/a)**n + 54365636569181/20000000000000)**(-m) - W

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It seems you are getting confused with the parenthesis. Try to separate them in multiple lines and do step-by-step first

Comment: I can give that a try.

Comment: Can any one suggest, a function that can be used instead to solve this Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `sp.log` instead of `np.log`. I run your code but it seems like the equation is too complex and no algorithms are implemented to solve it.

Comment: I am just trying to solve for x. Can you share more about no algorithms being implemented to solve the equation.

Comment: @SDS You want to solve a symbol equation, so you need to use `log` function given by sympy. Change all `np.log` in your code to `sp.log`. Usually this works but for your equation, I get an error `NotImplementedError: multiple generators [log((x/a)**n + 54365636569181/20000000000000)**m, log(1 + x/R)]`. Often this means that the solutions cannot be represented symbolically. See http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/solvers.html

Comment: I wasnt sure if sp.log = ln or log10, since I want to use ln.

Comment: Thanks!, I will try to use an alternate syntax to solve the equation.

Comment: @SDS it is ln. You can accept my answer if it gives a hand :)